# Compare if one JSON payload contains another JSON payload

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, contains

I have 3 `JSON` payloads: `A`, `B` and `C`. I need to find out if payload `A` contains `B` and `C`.

- When `B` is compared against `A`, I need the result to be `true`.
- When `C` is compared against `A`, I need the result to be `false`
  as `college` key does not exist in payload `A`.

Note: Below `JSON` payloads are just examples and can have different structure and values.

Payload `A`:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "search": {
    "name": "Testing",
    "age": "25",
    "school": "sacred heart"
  },
  "Address": {
    "street": "Abcedf",
    "road": "4th cross",
    "city": "bangalore"
  }
}
```

Payload `B`

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "search": {
    "name": "Testing"
  },
  "Address": {
    "street": "Abcedf",
    "road": "4th cross"
  }
}
```

Payload `C`

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "search": {
    "name": "Testing",
    "college": "global"
  },
  "Address": {
    "street": "Abcedf",
    "road": "4th cross"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to create Java objects from your Json. You can use Gson, Jackson or any other library of your choice. For this example I have used Gson.

Your class definition

```
    private class JsonObject {

       String id;
       Map search;
       @SerializedName(value="Address")
       Map address;

       // getter and setter
    }
```

Parsing objects ( a,b and c are your Json Strings )

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonObject objectA = gson.fromJson( a, JsonObject.class);
    JsonObject objectB = gson.fromJson( b, JsonObject.class);
    JsonObject objectC = gson.fromJson( c, JsonObject.class);
```

For the actual comparison there are many ways to accomplish what you need. One way would be to implement your own method for comparing the objects

```
    private static boolean check( JsonObject firstObject, JsonObject secondObject ) {
    return firstObject.getAddress().entrySet().containsAll( secondObject.getAddress().entrySet()  )
            && firstObject.getSearch().entrySet().containsAll( secondObject.getSearch().entrySet() );
}
```

Call the method

```
    System.out.println( check ( objectA, objectB ) );
    System.out.println( check ( objectA, objectC ) );
```

Result

```
true
false
```

Your can, of course create your own logic to compare your Maps inside the objects. Take a look at [Java Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) or the [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library which offers some handy utility methods for working with Collections.

Comment: Hey thanks for the ans but the jsons are generic and not static. Above jsons are just an example. It is not defined actually. Sorry I forgot to mention that in my question. I will add it in my question now.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise [JsonPointer](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-json-pointer-03) to implement `contains` method. `A.contains(B)` method returns `true` when object `A` contains all pointers which has object `B` and all values are the same. Two objects (`A` and `B`) are `equal` when `A.contains(B)` and `B.contains(A)`. From definition: `A.contains(A)` returns `true` for every `A`.

Simple implementation could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonPointer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class JsonPointersApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File aJsonFile = new File("./resource/a.json").getAbsoluteFile();
        File bJsonFile = new File("./resource/b.json").getAbsoluteFile();
        File cJsonFile = new File("./resource/c.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonPayload payloadA = new JsonPayload(mapper.readTree(aJsonFile));
        JsonPayload payloadB = new JsonPayload(mapper.readTree(bJsonFile));
        JsonPayload payloadC = new JsonPayload(mapper.readTree(cJsonFile));
        System.out.println("JSON A:" + payloadA);
        System.out.println("JSON B:" + payloadB);
        System.out.println("JSON C:" + payloadC);
        System.out.println("A contains B:" + payloadA.contains(payloadB));
        System.out.println("A contains C:" + payloadA.contains(payloadC));
        System.out.println("B contains C:" + payloadB.contains(payloadC));
        System.out.println("C contains B:" + payloadC.contains(payloadB));
        System.out.println("A contains A:" + payloadA.contains(payloadA));
    }
}

class JsonPayload {

    private final JsonNode root;
    private final List<JsonPointer> pointers = new ArrayList<>();

    JsonPayload(JsonNode root) {
        this.root = Objects.requireNonNull(root);
        findPointers(this.root, "");
    }

    public boolean contains(JsonPayload other) {
        //If number of pointers are different, JSON payloads are also different
        if (this.pointers.size() < other.pointers.size()) {
            return false;
        }
        // If pointers are not the same
        if (!this.pointers.containsAll(other.pointers)) {
            return false;
        }
        // check values
        return other.pointers
                .stream()
                .allMatch(p -> this.root.at(p).equals(other.root.at(p)));
    }

    private void findPointers(JsonNode node, String path) {
        if (node.isObject()) {
            node.fields().forEachRemaining(entry -> findPointers(entry.getValue(), path + "/" + entry.getKey()));
        } else if (node.isArray()) {
            final int size = node.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                findPointers(node.get(i), path + "/" + i);
            }
        } else {
            pointers.add(JsonPointer.compile(path));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return pointers.toString();
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
JSON A:[/id, /search/name, /search/age, /search/school, /Address/street, /Address/road, /Address/city]
JSON B:[/id, /search/name, /Address/street, /Address/road]
JSON C:[/id, /search/name, /search/college, /Address/street, /Address/road]
A contains B:true
A contains C:false
B contains C:false
C contains B:true
A contains A:true
```